# capistrano - write database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I try to write an capistrano deploy script to set the database credentials through user input.

In my deploy file:

```
after "deploy:update_code", "db:write_credentials"
namespace :db do
task :write_credentials do
    @username = Capistrano::CLI.password_prompt('mysql_username: ')
    @password = Capistrano::CLI.password_prompt('mysql_password: ')
    @config = YAML::load(File.open("#{current_path}/config/database.yml"))['production']
    @config["username"] = @username
    @config["password"] = @password
  end
end
```

After running 'cap deploy' and entering the username and password the script fails with the message "No such file or directory - /var/www/rails_app/current/config/database.yml (Errno::ENOENT)".

The file under this path exists on the server, I also have it in my git repo.

I can't figure out why the file can't be found.
Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Yaml::load` is executed locally on your machine from which you run `cap deploy` this is why that file is not found it is not being searched remotely.

Take a look at this gem: [capistrano-recipes](https://github.com/webficient/capistrano-recipes), if you want you can use that. Otherwise to learn how they're doing [here](https://github.com/webficient/capistrano-recipes/blob/master/lib/recipes/db.rb)

For completeness here are how you can read a remote file in a cap recipe

```
file = capture "cat #{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
```

[capture](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-DSL-Action-Inspection-Capture) will execute a **remote** command and return its output as a string.

Comment: DO NOT USE capture!! capture will only work for the 1st server, if the other servers generated a different out, you would not notice!